# Should I use primary key to identify records I want to delete from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Questions table, primary key of this table is "id" with auto increment.
Now i am creating a control panel for manage questions. one of the capability in control panel is delete questions.
Now my question: i want send primary key of Questions table to client as identifier of a HTML tag so that when user click on the HTML tag for delete the question, primary key of question send to server for delete question. Is it a dangerous in terms of security? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to follow but if it boils down to "should I use primary key to identify records I want to delete from a table?" then the answer is "yes".  As for security, it's the responsibility of the server script to determine that the request is being made by a valid user and that user has the authority to delete questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is related to using the primary key versus any other set of unique columns to identify the record to delete, there is no difference in the security at the database level.

For example if you have a table with the following columns:

```
id - primary key
subject -
serial_number -
...
other fields
```

Where `subject + serial_number` or unique for each row, it makes no difference in terms of security whether you do

```
delete from table where id = '&id'
```

versus

```
delete from table where serial_number = '&1' and subject = '&2'
```

A delete using the primary key might well be faster.

However since this delete is being triggered from an html page, you will definitely need to look at how to secure the page and prevent accidental deletions, but that has no bearing on the decision to use the primary key versus any other field to delete the record.

Answer (score 2):

Every request has to be validated, regardless of it coming in the form of a HTTP GET with an id, or a POST, or a web service call.

A properly made web-site needs protection against bots which relies on IP address tracking and request frequency analysis; hiding ids might stop some people from writing a shell script to get a sequence of objects, but there are other ways to exploit a web site by using a brute force attack of some sort.

ICQ ids are valuable but only because they're related to users and are a user's primary means of identification; it's a one-of-a-kind approach to user authentication, not used by any other service, program or web-site.

Conclusion  Yes, you need to worry about scrapers and DDOS attacks and data protection and a whole bunch of other stuff, but hiding ids will not properly solve any of those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you are going to use

```
<a href="YOUR_URL_TO_DELETE/ID_TO_DELETE">YOUR_ANCHOR</a>
```

the main problem thah I encounter with this approach is that every script that can follow links can delete records in your table. Consider using a form with POST method and show a confirm dialog to the user before doing the request.

Comment: The question is very difficult to follow, but I guess it could also boil down to "Should I use a GET for operations that change state?", to which the answer is "probably not".  While the HTTP specs don't forbid GET requests that change a server's state, they are strongly discouraged